# how to run gradle with class files inside the build folder?

Tags: java, gradle

I am creating RESTAPI application using gradle. I would like to deploy to server without the original java source code.
`./gradlew build` will generate build folder, however, `./gradlew run` will also generate build folder and run the class files, resources folder and jars in build folder.

Is it possible to skip the generate build folder and run the build folder directly? If not, how can i start gradle with class files, jars and resources folder?

Comment: Java code needs to be compiled (unless you have everything in a single .java file, which you can run straight from the shell, and even then compilation happens in the background). Gradle tasks depend on each other, so `run` will always have `build` happen first. You cannot skip building as the JVM runs the .class files (maybe inside a .jar), not the .java files.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. If you don't generate the build folder and it doesn't exist, you cannot run it. What do you mean by starting gradle with class files, jars and resource folder? Gradle is a build tool, it's purpose is to create class files and jars.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to deploy class file so that the original java code is not expose to other.

Comment: You can just deploy (or give away) .class files (or first bundle them in .jar or .war files); no need to include the .java files. If .java files end up in your .jar files, check your directory structure and how you build. That said, there are tools that recreate source code from .class files. You can make the recreated source code harder to understand by using an obfuscator.